# mht files doesn't appear on moss search

Tags: moss

The moss search doesn't find a mht files, I installed ifilter to mht on the server and iisreset and it doesn't work.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add your extension to the file formats indexed.
[Check out this post for doing zips](http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2008/11/10/sharepoint-2007-and-zip-indexing.aspx)

Also make sure the ifilter is 32bit if you are running 32bit MOSS, and 64bit if you are running 64bit MOSS.